# NO-WORK: char * ZZZ = system("/14/test");

Tags: c

I am trying to put the result from:

```
system("/14/test");
```

into a variable named "**ZZZ**" and then **printf** it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char ZZZ[10];

int main()
{

char * ZZZ = system("/14/test");

printf(ZZZ);



}
```

**Error:**

> warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
>   [-Wint-conversion]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`system()` doesn't capture the output of the command it runs - just the return code of command is returned by it.

Use [`popen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/popen.html) and read from the `FILE*` using `fgets()`. Something like:

```
char buf[1024];
FILE *fp = popen("/14/test", "r");

while(fgets(fp, buf, sizeof buf)) {
   printf("%s\n", buf);
}
```

Comment: tried both your example as well as the example in the link. not working. **error: ‘PATH_MAX’ undeclared here (not in a function)
 char path[PATH_MAX];** strange stuff.

Comment: Include `#include <limits.h>` to get `PATH_MAX`.

Comment: Note that `popen` captures only the standard output from the program, and though sometimes this is all you want, it's common to want the standard error stream as well.

On Linux one can do `fp = popen("/14/test 2>&1", "r");` to route the standard error stream as well.